# Impala SQL: Grouping records based on sequenced type and year

Tags: sql, impala

Given the following raw data, how would you group them to have the rank field in the desired outputs:
The built-in dense_rank and rank functions do not seem to work here because they always end up grouping the Type Bs together, instead of splitting them in 2 ranks. Please advise!

Raw Data:

```
ID Type Year
1   A   1998
2   B   1999
3   B   2000
4   C   2001
5   B   2002
6   B   2004
7   B   2020
```

Desired Output:

```
ID Type Year Rank
1   A   1998  1
2   B   1999  2
3   B   2000  2
4   C   2001  3
5   B   2002  4
6   B   2004  4
7   B   2020  4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()` to see the previous value and then a cumulative sum to count when the values change:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when type = prev_type then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as rank
from (select t.*, lag(type) over (order by id) as prev_type
      from t
     ) t;
```